# Show final record in the page header

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to show the sum sum bank 1 in the page header. I have 4 records to sumnate for bank 1:

```
1.100000
2.200000
3.250000
4.150000
5.200000
```

Crystal shows the first record `1.100000` in the header, but i want last record `5.200000`. I just using this formula `{Chc.CheckDate} in {?az} to {?ta}`

How can I show it?

Answer (score 0):

The header always grabs the first value, because the report evaluates top to bottom. By the time it reaches the header, it's only seen one record.

You can cheat this by putting a Subreport in your header. Have this Subreport sort the records descending (5, 4, 3, 2, 1) then put the field in the header of the Subreport. All it will show is the final record, `5.200000`.